# xCode push notifications. Size of array has non-integer type

Tags: php, xcode

I am having a problem with Push Notifications. In my App Delegate I have:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo {



UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
{
    NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
    NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
    NSString *message = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"alert"];


    UIAlertView *alertView [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                       message:message
                                                      delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                            otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil] ];


    [alertView show];
}
```

The json code I am sending from the sever is:

```
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'badge' => 1,
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'sms-received1.caf '


);
```

Can any one see why I am getting this error: Size of array has non-integer type (UIAvertView)

Many thanks foir any help.

Cheers,

DCJ

Comment: What language is that? PHP?  Please tag your question correctly ("xcode" doesn't cover all the technology used in your question - in fact it's irrelevant).

Comment: RESOLVED: I have too many brackets.